# Handle exception when allocating object in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, exception

Done a bit of reading on the subject and aren't able to come to a conclusion. If I'm trying to allocate a QFile (For example) on the heap and if the file is throwing some kind of exception, I would like to discard it and continue on with the next object (recovering will not be an issue). Some of my code looks like this:

```
void FileUploader::uploadNext() {
    if(!canceled_) {

        if((iterator_ + 1) < (start_ + offset_)) {
            iterator_++;

            _mutex.lock();// lock the fileList for the other threads. 
            fileList_[iterator_].uploadStarted();

            try {
                _item = new QFile((fileList_.at(iterator_).fileInfo()).filePath());

            } catch(std::bad_alloc) {
                // emit error
                // log
                _mutex.unlock();
                return uploadNext(); // upload next
            }
                            // in setupInfoFile I also want to try-catch so I dont set the objects properties if it wasen't allocated. 
            InfoFile *temp = this->setupInfoFile("test", fileList_.at(iterator_).fileInfo(), false);

            if(temp != NULL) {
                temp ->setSomething("test")
                _mutex.unlock();
                                    // send the file to a networkAccessManager that will come back with signals 
                _realFileUploader->addFile(temp, _item);

            } else {

                _mutex.unlock();
                _item->deleteLater();

                // emit error
                // log

                return uploadNext();
            }

            emit statusChangedAt(iterator_);

        } else emit finished();
    } else emit canceled();
}
```

Here I have a shared list (shared with other threads, hence the locking) which I will step through and create two objects that I will try and upload. If it fails in anyway I want to recover from it and upload next item. How would I do this?

After reading the Qt doc some objects just returns a Null pointer if the allocation failed since some os doesnt even throw the bad_alloc exception. They also recomended to put the try-catch block around main which will handle any exceptions regarding for example memory and then let the app exit. I don't want that.

So how can I handle exceptions or do error handeling in this situation? And what does Qt mean by this sentence?

> Currently, the only supported use case for recovering from exceptions thrown within Qt (for example due to out of memory) is to exit the event loop and do some cleanup before exiting the application.

Thanks!

Also: This might be a really stupid question, but how deep does the locking goes if I would create a QMutexLocker on the stack in the function which will goes out of scope when en error occurs? Does the lock work like a normal variable on the stack in terms of that it wouldnt lock stuff in the called functions aswell?

Comment: The problem here is that if you cannot allocate space for one QFile, you will probably fail on the next one as well.

Comment: so should i catch anything when allocation for the QFile or should the app just die gracefully?

Comment: also, if I dont catch the exceptions, will the mutex be unlocked or will i get a deadlock?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you allocate a pointer with new, and you have a moderately recent compiler, it should throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception in case of memory exhaustion. 
   And Qt, unless the docs of the particular function you want to use says otherwise, throws `bad_alloc` exceptions if an internal call to `malloc` fails, and that's probably the only type exception it throws.
2. The sentence you cited probably means that when an exception occurs and isn't caught before reaching the event loop, the only place where you can catch it next is around the `exec()` call.
3. `QMutexLocker` is meant to be allocated on the stack, and will unlock the mutex when the variable goes out of scope (see [the RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)).

   You should probably also wrap any raw pointer inside a smart pointer (e.g.: `QScopedPointer`, `QSharedPointer` or their array variants), to allow them to be deallocated automatically if you don't reach the end of the scope because an exception occured.

With all that, and without trying to catch exceptions, because any further memory allocation is likely to fail anyway, your code would look like this:

```
void FileUploader::uploadNext()
{
    if(canceled_) {
        emit canceled();
        return;
    }

    if ( ++iterator_ >= (start_ + offset_)) {
        emit finished();
        return;
    };

    QMutexLocker locker(mutex);
    fileList_[iterator_].uploadStarted();

    QScopedPointer<QFile> item(
       new QFile((fileList_.at(iterator_).fileInfo()).filePath()));

    QScopedPointer<InfoFile> temp(
        this->setupInfoFile("test", fileList_.at(iterator_).fileInfo(), false));

    temp->setSomething("test")    
    _realFileUploader->addFile(temp.data(), item.data());

    // remove the pointer from the QScopedPointers guard
    temp.take();
    item.take();

    emit statusChangedAt(iterator_);
}
```

Comment: i changed the mutexlocker to a QMutexLocker locker(&mutex) which will go out of scope. is there any other way to handle this particilur problem without exceptions? maybe std::nothrow and check for nullpointer?

Comment: Any QString that you allocate can throw an exception, the only thing you can do is write exception safe code by heavily using the RAII idiom. And if you were to use nothrow and test for null, the normal execution path would be less clear for any people reading your code, and a little bit slower because of the explicit test.

Comment: but now the pointer to the file will die when it run out of scope right? the fileUploader uses the QNetworkAccessManager which will upload the file, which means that I need both of the objects to be alive and kicking until the request is finished.

Comment: They will only be deleted, if you didn't call `take` before the pointers go out of scope. It may be easier with `QSharedPointer` and if the `addFile` function took `QSharedPointer` too instead of raw pointer, because you wouldn't have to call `take` manually (at the cost of adding a reference counter to the pointer).